# `nixos-rebuild switch` gets stuck when using `builtins.fetchGit`

Tags: version-control, package, nix, nixos, system-configuration

I'm trying to download a package with a version that is not on **nixpkgs**. To do so, I'm using `builtins.fetchGit`. Here's a summary of the file where I use `fetchGit` (`/etc/nixos/home/core.nix`) for a better idea:

```hs
{ pkgs, username, homeDirectory }:

############################
# Custom package snapshots #
############################

let custom-ver-pkgs = {
  # Haskell Language Server
  hls = let pkgsSnapshot = import (builtins.fetchGit {
      name = "custom hls version";
      url = "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs-channels/";
      ref = "refs/heads/nixpkgs-unstable";                     
      rev = "2c162d49cd5b979eb66ff1653aecaeaa01690fcc";
    }) {}; in pkgsSnapshot.haskellPackages.haskell-language-server;
};

in

{
  # Actual config
}
```

And here's the point where I use the `hls` keyword defined above:

```hs
  # Packages
  home.packages = with pkgs; [
    ... # Normal packages
  ] ++

  # Packages with custom version (See start of file)
  (with custom-ver-pkgs; [
    hls
  ]);
```

As you can see, I also use home-manager. The above-mentioned `.../core.nix` file is imported directly into `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

As the title says, if I run `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`, the terminal freezes (in the sense that the command goes on forever without doing anything). What could my problem be?

Comment: Nix shouldn't just stop. Which version of Nix are you using? Please try with one or more `-v` flags to figure out what Nix was doing before it stopped.

Comment: I ran `sudo nixos-rebuild -v switch` and the terminal froze (or at least it went without doing anything for 10 min) after this line: `fetching Git repository 'https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs-channels/'...`

Comment: Just kidding... immediately after I wrote the terminal continued with something along the lines of `error: malformed name fields; no spaces allowed`. I will from now on always use the `-v` flag... tank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried just using an overlay to redefine the package source?